# jQuery: Iterating a hash containing a key 'length'

Tags: jquery, hash, key, loops

I have a JS-hash containing a key `length` (which represents something completely different than the length of the hash) and need to iterate over it.

The problem is that `jQuery.each` is refusing to iterate over this since it detects the `length` attribute and figures that it must be an array or array-like object.

From the jQuery documentation:

> Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) > are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their
>   named properties.

[This JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHWpc/) illustrates the problem.

Well, so it's all documented and understandable. But how to proceed if I just *have* an attribute named `length`? Do I have to do a painful renaming before and after iterating the hash, or is there any possibility of telling jQuery to just ignore this property and treat it like any other object attribute?

Thank's a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about not using jquery.each but...

```
for (var key in testHash2) {
    if (testHash2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $('#result').append($('<li />').text(key + ':' + testHash2[key]));
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**
forgot to sanitise the loop with "hasOwnProperty" just in case...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick patch that fixes that behaviour:

```
(function($,undefined){
    var initialEach = $.each;
    $.each = function(obj,fn){
       if($.isArray(obj) || obj.length === undefined)
           return initialEach.apply(this,arguments);
       // else iterate over the object that contains a 'length' property
       for(var key in obj)
           if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                fn.call(obj[key],key,obj[key]);
    };
 })(jQuery);
```

Here's a live demo to straighten things up : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/vwWm6/